# Отступ между блоками

Tags: css

На странице https://zigzag.kg/otzyvy/ отступы между отзывами велики. Как их сократить? 
Вот css:

```
 .otzyvy {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row; 
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-content:center;


}

.item_otz {
    padding:0;

}



.item_otz_text {
    margin-left:10px;
    padding:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#949494;
}

.item_otz_img {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    max-height:320px;
}
```

Между отзывами отступ должен быть 30 px.

Comment: Для .item_otz_img поставьте height:auto, а max-height:320px; уберите

Comment: WordPress тут ни при чём.

Answer (score 0):

```
.otzyvy {
display:flex;
flex-direction:row; 
justify-content:space-between;
align-content:center;
}

.item_otz {
    padding:0;
}

.item_otz_text {
    margin-left:10px;
    padding:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#949494;
}
.item_otz_img {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Но как только я добавляю flex-wrap:wrap . Они по одному идут. Нужно чтобы последний только опускался на следующую строку.

Comment: Добавьте для .item_otz {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
} Если хотите 3 в ряд, есле другое число, другую цифру вместо 3

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы в мобильной ширине они по 2 блока шли ?

Comment: Добавьте медиазапрос: например @media (max-width: 768px){ .item_otz { width: calc(100% / 2); } }